# Standard Deviation from multiple files in bash

Tags: bash, awk, average, standard-deviation

I wish to calculate the standard deviation from a range of files titled "res_NUMBER.cs" which are formatted as a CSV. Example data includes

```
1,M,CA,54.9130  
1,M,CA,54.9531  
1,M,CA,54.8845  
1,M,CA,54.7517  
1,M,CA,54.8425  
1,M,CA,55.2648  
1,M,CA,55.0876
```

I have calculated the mean using

```
#!/bin/bash


files=`ls res*.cs`  
for f in $files; do 
        echo "$f" 
        echo " " 
        #Count number of lines N 
        lines=`cat $f | wc -l` 
        #Sum Total 
        sum=`cat $f | awk -F "," '{print $4}' | paste -sd+ | bc` 
        #Mean 
        mean=`echo "scale=5 ; $sum / $lines" | bc` 
        echo "$mean" 
        echo " "
```

I would like to calculate the standard deviation across each file. I understand that the standard deviation formula is

```
S.D=sqrt((1/N)*(sum of (value - mean)^2))
```

But I am unsure how I would implement this into my script.

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: @Cyrus I am sorry I didn't format the post correctly, I hope this is formatted correctly now.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with concise, testable sample input, expected output and your attempt to solve the problem yourself so we can help you further. See [ask] and look at existing questions that have been upvoted and answered for examples. Also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and look at existing questions that have been upvoted and answered to see how to format your input, outpu, and code as "Code Blocks" and then [edit] your question to do so

Comment: There are a *lot* of issues with`files=$(ls res*.cs); for f in $files`.  It is much less fragile to do `for f in res*.cs; do ...`

Comment: If you are not strictly limited to AWK then I suggest taking look at [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) as it has ready statistical functions, note that `datamash` has 2 different standard deviation functions: `pstdev` and `sstdev` so you must firstly detect which one you do want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` is powerful enough to calculate the mean of one file easily

```
$ awk -F, '{sum+=$4} END{print sum/NR}' file
```

to add standard deviation (not that your formula is for population, not for sample, that's what I replicate here)

```
 $ awk -F, '{sum+=$4; ss+=$4^2} END{print m=sum/NR,sqrt(ss/NR-m^2)}' file
 54.9567 0.15778
```

this uses the fact that stddev = sqrt(Var(x)) = sqrt( E(x^2) - E(x)^2 )
which has worse numerical accuracy (since squaring the values instead of diff) but works fine if your values have low bounds.

The simplest is then using this in a for loop for the files

```
for f in res*.cs
do 
    awk -F, '{sum+=$4; ss+=$4^2} 
         END {print FILENAME; 
              print "mean:", m=sum/NR, "stddev:", sqrt(ss/NR-m^2)}' "$f"
end
```

to run res1.cs .. res37.cs in that order, easiest is change the for loop

```
for f in res{1..37}.cs
# the rest of the code not changed.
```

which will expand in the numerical order specified.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question, this worked perfectly. Im not sure if I need to create a new forum post but I expected the output to be in the format of res1, res2, and res3 ... not what is outputted in res10, res11, res12.....res1. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: That's your file order, change the for loop to `for f in res{1..12}.cv'

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your comment. I have 37 files called res1, res2, res3.....res36,res37. I would like them outputted.